# How to build a day counter streak in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, counter

I am making a learning app like Duolingo App using Flutter. I want to put a streak counter which checks if you have visited the app for that day and if you completed a lesson, it will increment by +1 and if you miss for a day, the counter will reset to 0. How can I achieve it with Flutter and Firebase?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can save and update date in firebase whenever the user open your application.

Now, when user open your app that time you have to fetch date from firebase and you have to compare with today’s date. if day difference is more than 1 day then you have to reset counter other wise you have to increment counter by one.

Comment: Well, you answer seems to be correct but it might fail in some cases like, if today's date is `1` then the difference will be higher..right..!

Comment: No actually @srikanth7785 because if you store whole date in firebase and also subtract that date from today’s date then it will 1 only.

Comment: Try following code.    DateTime date = DateTime(2020,1,31);
  DateTime today = DateTime(2020,2,1);
  print(today.difference(date).inDays.toString());

Comment: Ohh.. okay fine..I didn't know that.. thanks for the information..